# When should an iterator return an IEnumerator instead of an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable, ienumerator

Using `yield return` turns a method into an iterator. [The return type of an iterator must be `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerator`, or `IEnumerator<T>`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield#iterator-methods-and-get-accessors)

I have found that an iterator can only be used in a `foreach` loop if it returns one of the `IEnumerable` types. Given this limitation, when would it make sense to choose an `IEnumerator` return type instead of an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: The only place I've seen an iterator method returning an `IEnumerator` is for [Unity's coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). I assume this is because they're (ab)using the iterator machinery to do something different, and don't want people accidentally thinking they should be looping over the coroutine.

Comment: I acutally thought that this code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KOMtuL - would crash, since I am only returning the interface `IEnumerator` so who acutally implements the method `MoveNext()` ?!? Magic?

Comment: @RandRandom [Demystified](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4B0AwhADZ0xgAuAlhAHYDOA3ISeRwo+BAJDjx/AMzksggOyEA3oVHYsqlWNEA3AIZRSCUgF5SAMQgQAFAEoR4gO4ALVo2sJKAWQg6YAORgEZjtbVXEKAE4PGgBXKFgOZntVAF9VVQwZCiRSAEkAUQ5YgFsYKD1maAsrO01wihxyeVIAIgAJGAYIUgB1aDoAE1aHdIJUoA===)

Comment: @RandRandom The block of code will be compiled into an IEnumerator state machine that will handle the MoveNext and Current.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty rarely, to be honest. The only times I've seen it used that way is when special-casing things for some reason **in the `GetEnumerator()` method** (before firing up the iterator block machinery), but still wanting an iterator block for the actual implementation, i.e.

```cs
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    if (someScenario) return SomethingSpecialPerhapsEmptyArrayEnumerator();
    if (anotherScenario) ThrowSomeException();
    return DoTheThing();
}
private IEnumerator<T> DoTheThing()
{
    // ... yield return
}
```

Comment: So `GetEnumerator` is automatically generated if an iterator returns `IEnumerable` but not if it returns `IEnumerator`? Are there any other differences between the two return types?

Comment: @user200783 that's mostly it